# What vulnerability query params or body outside a whitelist can allow?

Tags: http, webserver

For instance, suppose we have a request that uses the field `name` in a request's body or query params, but the client sends the params `name` and `age`. Some web server frameworks allow us to strip properties outside a whitelist so this `age` param would be stripped. But, if my application only accesses the property `name`, what harm can extra properties make?

Comment: That depends on what your server does with those params, even unexpected ones...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It depends.**

Without knowing anything about the application, one general risk that might be relevant is [HTTP flooding attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Flood), which is a type of [Resource exhaustion attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_exhaustion_attack).

The application *may* use **regular expressions** to parse requests, especially GET requests. Regular expressions, depending on their complexity, may take a lot of CPU and memory resources. Also, depending on expression, resource consumption can grow not linearly, but exponentially with the input length (with the length of URL in GET request). By the same URL length, splitting it into more parameters can again increase resource consumption by regular exception parser.

The application *may* use **XSS sanitizing**. This again often means that regular expression parser is involved. Even without regular expressions, analysis regarding XSS can take much resources.

Depending on the architecture, there *may* be a web server, one or more reverse proxies (independent on web server), and the application that implements the business logic. In such case big volume of data would be send across several **network** segments, which again means wasting of resources.

Depending on the architecture and software used, there *may* some kind of **cache** where the request is stored. Again, this would mean resource wasting.

If the application writes every request completely to the **log**, and the log events are sent via network to some storage (ElasticSearch, Splunk, whatever), this is again resource wasting.

If there is a single such request a day, this might not be an issue. Also if payload size is relatively small and a superfluous parameter changes payload size from 50 to 100 bytes, this might not be an issue. But if there are 1'000 parameters (attributes, fields) or if the payload size is 10 MB instead of 100 B and you get 1'000 or 10'000 such requests per second, this *may* be an issue.

What can you do? Set limits. Not sure how big they should be? Set them e.g. 10 time higher than typical requests you observed so far. Better big limits than no limits at all. This makes sense in combination with other limits (total request rate, request rate per IP).